Choosing a unique visitor on the fly
I've been thinking of this as the "Prize of the Week" problem. Suppose you run a shop, and want to give out a prize once a week to someone making a randomly-selected purchase. You give out the prize at the time the purchase is made, but want to make sure exactly one prize is given out each week. What's the best way to choose whether to award the prize as part of a given transaction?
As a first approximation, I could choose randomly with a probability of one over the average number of transactions per week. Once a prize is given, I could not check until a new week starts, to give no more than one prize during the week.
But that doesn't address the possibility of no one being chosen. It seems like the probability of awarding the prize should rise toward the end of the week. Does this distribution have a name I could look up for further reading?
I realize the problem has no perfect solution. Usually Friday is busy, but occasionally it happens that just no one comes in after lunch. I'm also looking for ideas on how to model this and bound the probability of failing to award based on typical behaviour.

How about giving the prize (if it has not yet been awarded) to each customer with probability $\dfrac{1}{1+\text{ expected number of further customers later in the week}}$

Yes, something like that. :)
